# How to lock current screen view in Google Sheets (using App Script or else)?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I had set up a Stock Calculator in Google sheet for some Laymen Users.I need to ensure that its current current view does not change and users only see the intended area?

- can I lock scrolling and zooming using App Script
- I already tried freezing option. but not useful in my Case.

Comment: Just hide rows that should not be seen and restrict all but the entry area to your own edits

Answer (score 0):

- drag this bold line where you need to
- done

[image: 0]